# How to smooth the Linestring after adding additional point?

Tags: python, geometry, shapely, linestring

Actually I am tracking vessel, where I am already having path, and current position. Now the trouble is, obviously the vessel will not be on same coordinates as provided in the path.So I want to connect the current coordinate with the path and willing get updated path.

I have already connected but the issue is with my way the vessel taking long route. Which will be problematic for ETA calculations.

Any suggestions?

For example, the original route end something look like this:
[image]

After current position update it should like this:
[image]

But my way I am getting this:

[image]

Here is my data and code:

```
p = {'route': [{'path': [[51.51309, 0.4836599999999862],
     [51.512222970577746, 0.4838196951935174],
     [51.50817683327391, 0.4845649394298732],
     [51.50730980385166, 0.484724634623376],
     [51.490146683273906, 0.6260075894298893],
     [51.410052120577745, 1.285328045193495],
     [51.392889, 1.4266110000000083],
     [51.35695154999999, 1.4217484499999955],
     [51.18924344999999, 1.3990565500000116],
     [51.153306, 1.3941939999999988],
     [50.939489249999994, 0.8940607000000114],
     [49.94167775, -1.4398946999999964],
     [49.727861, -1.9400280000000123],
     [49.54469854999999, -2.366040450000014],
     [48.689940449999995, -4.354098550000003],
     [48.506778, -4.780111000000005],
     [47.68888635, -5.458406800000006],
     [43.87205865, -8.62378720000001],
     [43.054167, -9.30208300000001],
     [42.41353785, -9.331828900000005],
     [39.42393515, -9.47064309999999],
     [38.783306, -9.500389000000013],
     [38.5191851, -9.424647249999992],
     [37.286620899999996, -9.071185750000012],
     [37.0225, -8.995443999999992],
     [36.86918755, -8.487389949999994],
     [36.15372945, -6.116471050000001],
     [36.000417, -5.608417000000003],
     [36.139162799999994, -4.182775300000003],
     [36.7866432, 2.4702192999999966],
     [36.925389, 3.8958609999999965],
     [36.98901405, 4.773231850000002],
     [37.285930949999994, 8.867629149999999],
     [37.349556, 9.745000000000005],
     [37.31056005, 9.939120849999995],
     [37.12857895, 10.845018149999987],
     [37.089583, 11.039139000000006],
     [36.25582884999999, 14.171143199999989],
     [32.36497615, 28.787162800000004],
     [31.531222, 31.919167000000016],
     [31.486459599999996, 31.97396710000001],
     [31.2775684, 32.22970090000001],
     [31.232806, 32.284501000000006],
     [31.036959999999997, 32.32685409999999],
     [30.123011999999996, 32.52450189999999],
     [29.927166, 32.566855000000004],
     [27.339266099999996, 34.20131845],
     [15.262399899999998, 41.828814550000004],
     [12.6745, 43.463278],
     [12.6860083, 43.699777900000015],
     [12.7397137, 44.80344410000001],
     [12.751222, 45.03994399999999],
     [12.944847099999999, 45.588698300000004],
     [13.8484309, 48.14955170000002],
     [14.042056, 48.698306],
     [14.27693095, 49.22293100000002],
     [15.37301405, 51.67118099999999],
     [15.607889, 52.195806000000005],
     [15.81688895, 52.6194309],
     [16.79222205, 54.5963471],
     [17.001222, 55.019971999999996],
     [17.138847, 55.21973030000001],
     [17.781097, 56.151935699999996],
     [17.918722, 56.35169400000001],
     [18.080792799999998, 56.575119],
     [18.8371232, 57.61776900000001],
     [18.999194, 57.841194],
     [19.4823149, 58.13619825000001],
     [21.736879099999996, 59.51288475000001],
     [22.22, 59.80788899999999],
     [22.840945849999997, 59.31257655000002],
     [25.73869315, 57.00111844999998],
     [26.359639, 56.50580600000001],
     [26.160997649670072, 56.29158290493038],
     [25.234004681463745, 55.29187512793891],
     [25.035363331133816, 55.07765203286928],
     [25.00255, 55.10811000000001]],
    'type': 'SEA'}]}

from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.ops import transform
from functools import partial
import pyproj
from shapely.ops import split
from itertools import chain


total_path=p['route'][0]['path'][1:-1] ##### Total path
total_line = LineString(total_path)


project = partial(
    pyproj.transform,
    pyproj.Proj('EPSG:4326'),
    pyproj.Proj('EPSG:32633'))
total_ls = transform(project, total_line)

total_distance = total_ls.length/1852   ######Tortal distance in NM
print(total_distance, "Distance")


current_pin = (13.752724664396988, 56.42578125)
position = Point(current_pin)
all_points_coords = chain(total_line.coords,position.coords)
all_points = map(Point, all_points_coords)
new_line = LineString(sorted(all_points, key=total_line.project))
new_ls = transform(project, new_line)
new_distance = new_ls.length/1852

## remain distance from current position
remain = LineString(new_line.coords[new_line.coords[:].index(current_pin):]) 
remain = transform(project, remain)
r_distance = remain.length/1852

print(r_distance,"remain distance")
print(r_distance/13)
new_ls
```

Comment: This is not a trivial problem, and you already have all the tools needed to make the change, so what have you tried? What rules do you want to apply for smoothing?

Comment: @Vince ,would be good if current position point will directly connect with line string two nearest vertices (before and after).  might be that make line string smooth . Please share your thought as well.